# Showing that, if Ω is a finite set, then  contains an even number of subsets of Ω

Tags: probability, combinatorics

While trying to answer the following question from the book '*Probability an introduction*' by Grimmett & Welsh (exercise 1.12):

Showing that, if Ω is a finite set, then  contains an even number of subsets of Ω

I bumped into a problem on how to show this in the correct way.

So far I understand that when you have a set, let's say {$1, 2, 3$}, that you can 'include or exclude' every element of the set.
Which will result in $2*2*2 = 2^3 = 8$.

Now should I just show show by induction that this counts for every $n$, in my example represented by $3$ (basically showing that all $2^n$ will lead to an even number) , or is there a different way on how I should approach this?

Comment: What is $\mathcal F$ here? Some ($\sigma$-)algebra maybe?

Comment: I just started the course and haven't seen anything about (σ-)algebra yet, but according to the book  is the collection of subsets of the sample space Ω, which is an event space if it satisfies those conditions.

Comment: If it is the collection of **all** subsets of $\Omega$ then the answer is quite easy. If not then it can be proved too. This because the collection is closed under the formation of complements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you are not necessarily dealing with the powerset of $\Omega$ (suspicuously easy) but with a subcollection of it.

Let $n$ be a positive natural number and let $\mathcal F\subseteq\wp(\{1,\dots,n\})$  with  $F\in\mathcal F\implies F^c\in\mathcal F$.

If $\mathcal F_0:=\{F\in\mathcal F\mid 1\in F\}$ and $\mathcal F_1:=\{F\in\mathcal F\mid 1\notin F\}$ then there is a one-to-one relation between $\mathcal F_0$ and $\mathcal F_1$ so that they have equal cardinality. Also we have $\mathcal F_0\cap\mathcal F_1=\varnothing$ and $\mathcal F_0\cup\mathcal F_1=\mathcal F$. This leads to:$$|\mathcal F|=|\mathcal F_0|+|\mathcal F_1|=2|\mathcal F_0|$$

Comment: What does this $p({1,...,n})$ notation mean?

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising $wp(A)$ denotes the power set of $A$. That is the set of subsets of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by induction with a 'special element' type of inductive step (the sets with this element, the sets without it, etc)

or you could simply produce a general proof (although this might prove harder, I think induction is probably easiest).
Additionally, you could draw a parallel from ${{n}\choose{i}}$ to 'all the possible subsets of cardinality $i$' and then use the proof that 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{i}} = 2^n
$$
Although that may count as circular reasoning unless you prove it algebraically and not with one of those 'combinatorial' proofs. (I would suggest using the Binomial Theorem for this separate proof.

Comment: I'm (of course) assuming that $\mathcal{F}$ is a powerset

Answer (score 0):

I know I am answering this a bit late, but I hope to help those who may come across this post in search of a different answer to the ones that have been provided. (If you find any error in my proof, don't hesitate to correct me.)

Let $=\{A_1, A_2, ..., A_n\}$ for some n in the natural numbers. Proving that  has an even number of subsets of $\Omega$ is just the same as proving that there exists a bijection that assigns for each X in  the set $\Omega-X$. In order to do prove the fact that this application is a 1-1 mapping, we only have to note that X and $\Omega-X$ are unique, i.e. there cannot be a set $U\neq X$ such that $\Omega-X = \Omega-U$. The proof of the last statement goes as follows: assume there is a set U such that the previous statement is satisfied. Then, as $U\neq X$, by the left-hand side of the previous equality we have that there is an x in $\Omega$ and U such that x is not in X. But that is impossible since the right-hand side of the equality is composed of those elements in the sample space that do not belong to U. (Additionally, note that we know that it is surjective application from the definition of an event space).

Having proved that there exists such a bijection, it is easy to see that the cardinality is even for if it was odd, there would be a set Y for which there would not be an image under such bijection, which is to say that $\Omega - Y$ is not in the event space. Hence, we have arrived at a contradiction.